# PreventDefault in bootstrap confirmation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-confirmation

When I use this code:

```
$(function() {
            $('#enableBtn{!! $zone->id !!}').on('confirmed.bs.confirmation', '', function () {
                e.preventDefault();

                // Do Ajax Here
                var ZoneId = 1;
                var value = 1;
                var published_at = $('#published_at').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: host + '/zone/toggleEnable',
                    data: {id: title, value: body},
                    success: function( msg ) {
                        alert('success');
                        //$("#ajaxResponse").append("<div>"+msg+"</div>");
                    }
                });

            });

        });
```

and i click on Yes in the confirmation popup, the e.preventDefault() doesn't work and the whole page reloads which is not a desired behavior since i need to call the ajax. Why is this happening ? How i can solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback function is missing its event parameter.  Try replacing this:

```
$('#enableBtn{!! $zone->id !!}').on('confirmed.bs.confirmation', '', function () {
```

with this:

```
$('#enableBtn{!! $zone->id !!}').on('confirmed.bs.confirmation', '', function (e) {
```

Note the addition of the **e** argument, which is now available to you on the next line:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Technically, I believe the `e` is a parameter.

Comment: I put 'e' but the page still reloads .. I think there should be something related to the confirmation bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how i figured it out but I was able to initialize my own confirmation custom box in the bootstrap confirmation initialization script. I replaced the anchor with a button and it worked:

```
$('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
        rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
        btnOkClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-success',
        btnCancelClass: 'btn btn-sm btn-danger',
        template: '<div class="popover confirmation">' +
        '<div class="arrow"></div>' +
        '<h3 class="popover-title"></h3>' +
        '<div class="popover-content">' +
        '<p class="confirmation-content"></p>' +
        '<div class="confirmation-buttons text-center">' +
        '<div class="btn-group">' +
        '<button class="btn" data-apply="confirmation"></button>' +
        '<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="confirmation"></a>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'});
```

Comment: I was recently facing the same issue, however changing the a-href to a button did not work for me with `e.preventDefault`. With the a-href I did never getting it working correctly but with your button solution I did when I put `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` in the logic handling on the first line. Just this works, however to be sure I also kept the `e.preventDefault()` just to be sure!